# Summing up an average column in ssrs

Tags: sum, average, ssrs-2012, calculated-columns, subtotal

I need some help with trying to Totaling a column that is taking an average.
The column has an expression of: =avg(Fields!UOS_2017.Value)
I want to sum this column so I would think I could simply do: =sum(avg(Fields!UOS_2017.Value)) 
BUT this does not work. The total should be 3,606. 
[Here are my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yJGT.png)

Here is my [Design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWtEZ.png)

**Update** I am attached a sample of the data that is being used to create the report.  [Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXPJA.png)

Will anyone help me with the expression I should be using or help with a custom code.  I appreciate any help. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have three row groups called something like

`VP Rollup`, `Director Rollup` and `Cost Center`

In this case you need to change your expression to be something like

```
=Sum(Avg(Fields!UOS_2017.Value, "Cost Center"))
```

This basically says "take the average at the `cost center` scope and then sum the results at the current scope (which would be at `Director Rollup` level).

Comment: Hello. Yes, that is correct three different groups for VP Rollup, Director Rollup & Cost Center. I used your suggestions and got this message: "The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox1255’ specifies a scope that is not valid for a nested aggregate.  The scope must be the same name of the scope specified by the outer aggregate or the name of a group or data region that is contained in the scope specified by the outer aggregate."

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Do you any other ideas I can try?

Comment: You need to make sure the scope is set to the name of the Cost Center row group. I just put "Cost Center" as I didn't know your exact group name. Check the row group names in the group panel below the main report design windows and make sure it's exactly the same name. if you still have trouble, edit the question to show the full design including the grouping panels.

Comment: Yes, I did. I check the Group Properties and under General it has Name: Cost_Center1.  This is the name I used.

Comment: I've tested this against some of my own data and it worked as expected. It might be a few days but I'll put together an RDL with sample data for you to look at and compare. In the meantime, if you can post some sample data that would save me some time.

Comment: Ok I apologize for the delay on getting the sample data posted. I am attached a screen shot.  Thanks.